# How can I set my Powershell so that it reads the Python modules from the standard library?

Tags: python, powershell

I'm learning to code in Python and am testing a basic script that utilizes the 'Turtle' module. Unfortunately, I keep receiving this error when I try to run my scrip from Window's Powershell:

```
PS C:\Python\Python_Practice> python turtlepracticeproblem.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "turtlepracticeproblem.py", line 1, in <module>
     import turtle
  File "C:\Python\Python_Practice\turtle.py", line 4, in <module>
     bob = turtle.Turtle
AttributeError: module 'turtle' has no attribute 'Turtle'
```

Here is the basic script also:

```
import turtle 

bob = turtle.Turtle()

def square(t, length):

for i in range(4):
    t.fd(length)
    t.lt(90)

square(bob, 100)
```

I've already tried to troubleshoot this issue by making sure that none of the variable are conflicting with anything already in the 'turtle' library and also making sure that my script title 'turtlepracticeproblem.py' doesn't conflict either, but it's been to no avail. I'm under the impression that the problem lies somewhere in a default directory that Powershell is looking for the modules in or some discrepancy in how i'm executing my scripts, but as of thus far, I've yet to find any solutions. Any solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Python is currently installed at 'C:\Python\Python35-32' and my Python_Practice folder(the one in which my script is contained) is at 'C:\Python\Python_Practice'

Comment: Briefly: don't name your file `turtle.py`. Name it something that doesn't conflict with other module names.

Comment: I feel like such a klutz. Apparently if you name a file in your current working directory something that is a duplicate of a file in the standard library, Python exports from the file in your current directory first before going to the standard library. I had an old file named turtle.py in my current directory that was causing the error. Your response pointed out my error by having me take a closer look at the location of the error. Thank you!